# hardware acceleration FFMPEG on Windows

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I've installed the latest gyan.dev full build on Windows 10,
I want to convert a sequence of png to an h265 .mp4 movie
and I'm successfully using this command

`ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 3840x2160 -i TEST_%04d.png -vcodec libx265 -crf 1  -pix_fmt yuv440p -hwaccel cuvid Y:\TEST.mp4`

I would like to take advantage of the hardware acceleration of my RTX2080 during the process,
but I can't find any resource or command to add since **-hwaccel** which I supposed to be enough,
doesn't works.

Any hint is highly appreciated!
Best and stay safe.

Comment: Thank you so much, all of your answers have been very helpful!
I've just another question, if I would export my image sequence into h265 lossless
is there any difference between using -cfr 0 and lossless=1 key?

ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 3840x2160 -i TEST_%04d.png -vcodec libx265 -crf 0  -pix_fmt yuv420p Y:\TEST_1.mp4 -hwaccel cuvid 

or


ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 3840x2160 -i TEST_%04d.png -vcodec libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 -pix_fmt yuv420p Y:\TEST_1.mp4 -hwaccel cuvid

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libx265` is a software encoder. It does not support hardware encoding.

What you want is to use one of the [hardware encoders](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro). For hardware h.264 you will want to use the `h264_nvenc` video codec or for h.265 the `hevc_nvenc`

`ffmpeg -r 60 -f image2 -s 3840x2160 -i TEST_%04d.png -vcodec hevc_nvenc -crf 1  -pix_fmt yuv440p -hwaccel cuvid Y:\TEST.mp4`

You can list the encoders available using `ffmpeg.exe -encoders` and look for ones that mention `NVIDIA` in the list. For my ffmpeg I get the following Nvidia encoders in that list

```
 V..... h264_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc                NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc_h264           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V..... nvenc_hevc           NVIDIA NVENC hevc encoder (codec hevc)
 V..... hevc_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC hevc encoder (codec hevc)
```

And you can list the encoder parameters using, for example, `ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_nvenc`

Comment: `-hwaccel` is an input option meant to set up accelerated decoding. pix fmt should be `yuv420p`

Comment: For Windows `hevc_mf` may also be an option, but I'm not sure if Gyan's builds supports it and I don't have any experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Mokubai, @Gyan and @llogan for their answers.

In case someone wants to use ffmepg hwaccel for h265 to h264 conversion, use this:

```
ffmpeg -encoders | findstr /ic:"NVIDIA"
```

You should see:

```
 V....D h264_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC H.264 encoder (codec h264)
 V....D hevc_nvenc           NVIDIA NVENC hevc encoder (codec hevc)
```

ffmpeg command:

```
ffmpeg.exe -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuda -i <input_file> -map 0  -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -pix_fmt yuv420p -preset hq <output_file>
```

It reduced the runtime by 4X for me, for a 30-minute video, on a GTX1060 card.

Cheers